# functions and arrays to calculate gpa

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

This is what I  have tried out but whenever I run the program it crashes and says error, although it compiles correctly. It asks me to enter department number but after that doesn't show me any output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
const int STDTs = 25;
const int DEPTs = 7;
void  initializeGPAs(double gpa[][DEPTs])
{
    for(int i=0;i<STDTs;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<DEPTs;j++)
        gpa[i][j]=(10+rand()%31)/10;
}
void computeDeptAvg(double gpa[][DEPTs] , double deptAvg[])
{

    for(int i=0;i<STDTs;i++)
    {
        int sum=0;

        for(int j=0;j<DEPTs;j++)
        sum+=gpa[j][i];

    deptAvg[i]=double(sum/STDTs);
    }
}
int StdsOnProbationCount(double gpa[][DEPTs])
{
    int ctr=0;
   for(int i=0;i<STDTs;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<DEPTs;j++)
        if(gpa[i][j]<2)
            ctr++;

            return ctr;
}

int StdsOnProbationCountinDeptX(double gpa[][DEPTs], int x)
{
    int ctr=0;
     for(int i=0;i<STDTs;i++)
        if(gpa[i][x-1]<2)
        ctr++;

        return ctr;
}

void showReport(double gpa[][DEPTs],string dept_names[], double deptAvg[], int ctr1, int ctr2, int x)
{
    cout<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<DEPTs;i++)
{
cout<<'\t'<<dept_names[i]<<"  ";
}
cout<<endl;
     for(int i=0;i<STDTs;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Student "<<i+1<<":    ";

        for(int j=0;j<DEPTs;j++)
            cout<<gpa[i][j]<<"   ";

        cout<<endl;

    }
    cout<<endl;

    for(int t=0;t<DEPTs;t++)
        cout<<"Dept Avg.:   "<<deptAvg[t]<<"  ";

        cout<<endl<<endl;

        cout<<"Total number of students who are on probation is: "<<ctr1;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Number of students who are on probation in "<<dept_names[x-1]<<" Dept. is "<<ctr2;

}
int main()
{
 double gpa[STDTs][DEPTs];
 int ctr1, ctr2, x;
 double deptAvg[DEPTs];
 string dept_names[DEPTs]={"MATH","STAT","COMP","PHYS","CHEM","BIOL","GEOL"};
 initializeGPAs(gpa);
 computeDeptAvg(gpa, deptAvg);
 ctr1 = StdsOnProbationCount(gpa);
 cout<<"Enter Department Number [1 to 7]: ";
 cin >> x;
 ctr2 = StdsOnProbationCountinDeptX(gpa, x);
 showReport(gpa, dept_names, deptAvg, ctr1, ctr2, x);
 return 0;
}
```

edit: I figured everything out but my problem seems to be in this function because it displays zeroes for all the department averages

```
void computeDeptAvg(double gpa[][DEPTs] , double deptAvg[])
{

    for(int i=0;i<STDTs;i++)
    {
        int sum=0;

        for(int j=0;j<DEPTs;j++)
        {
            sum+=gpa[j][i];
       deptAvg[j]=double(sum/STDTs*1.0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error? Show us the actual error message!

Comment: your program can crash when you access data you are not supposed to; in your case using out of bounds indexes on the matrix; things like..if(gpa[i][x-1]<2)  seems suspicious to me - are you sure x-1 is a valid index?

Comment: At this point learning to use the debugger would be beneficial to you by running to the point of error and examining what's in memory at that time.

Comment: @Pandrei It seems ok as you enter a number between `1` and `7` and not `0` and `6`.

Comment: @BenSteffan I meant to say that is works and asks me for the department number but after that it crashes and says q2,exe has stopped working

Comment: @Pandrei it should be okay because it takes the department number entered for example 3 and it should access the third one which 3-1

Comment: @Ðаn I've attached a picture of the question but I'm not sure how to make it show?

Comment: `deptAvg[i]=double(sum/STDTs);` Consider all the possible values that `i` might take on, and then take a look at how large you initialize `deptAvg` to be, and you'll find that you step out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I'll consider only your `computeDeptAvg` function.

- Your `sum` variable should be of type `double`, declaring it as an `int` makes all of your calculations (specifically the `sum+=gpa[j][i]` and `sum/STDTs`, which is an integer division) prone to truncating errors.
- You nested the two loops in the wrong order: You should sum the scores of all the students in a particular department in order to calculate the average of that department. Besides, `deptAvg[j]` is overwritten every time the outer loop is executed.
- You have declared `gpa` in `main` as a `double gpa[STDTs][DEPTs];`, but in your loops you are using `gpa[j][i]`, where `j` is in the range [0, **DEPTs**) and `i` in [0, **STDTs**).

A modified version could be:

```
void computeDeptAvg(double gpa[][DEPTs] , double deptAvg[])
{
    for(int d = 0; d < DEPTs; d++)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;

        for(int s = 0; s < STDTs; s++)
        {
            sum += gpa[s][d];
        }

        deptAvg[d] = sum / STDTs;
    }
}
```